# 304 response with Owin

Tags: c#, owin

Whats the correct way of doing a 304 response with Owin middleware?

I'm doing this

```
public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    var response = context.Response;
    response.ContentType = "application/javascript";
    response.StatusCode = 200;

    if (ClientCached(context.Request, scriptBuildDate))
    {
        response.StatusCode = 304;
        response.Headers["Content-Length"] = "0";
        return null;
    }
    response.Headers["Last-Modified"] = scriptBuildDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r");

    return context.Response.WriteAsync(js);
}
```

Returning `null` is that correct for empty body response? It works but I was wondering how its supposed to be setup

Comment: If you add the OWIN Framework to your solution, then you can throw HttpException in these situations and it will return whatever http status code you set in the exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be perfectly in line with specification you should use `Stream.Null` as this is the desired way of representing *no body* scenario.

```
public override Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
{
    var response = context.Response;
    response.ContentType = "application/javascript";

    if (ClientCached(context.Request, scriptBuildDate))
    {
        response.StatusCode = 304;

        //Close the existing body just in case
        response.Body.Close();
        response.Body = Stream.Null;

        return Task.FromResult<Object>(null);
    }
    else
    {
        response.StatusCode = 200;
        response.Headers["Last-Modified"] = scriptBuildDate.ToUniversalTime().ToString("r");

        return context.Response.WriteAsync(js);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Anders Sorry my mistake. You can return null like you previously did or finished task for example Task.FromResult<Object>(null). The actual value you are returning is not part of response but a "synchronization point" (a standard async/await code). You previous solution worked as expected because the body stream was empty.  So it was writting nothing to the response, setting body stream to Stream.Null tells Owin that your goal is to have no body.

Comment: thanks, I get 500 sometimes after iisreset AND if the content is not modified so something is not right with my code thats execute when ClientCached, will try Task.FromResult<Object>(null) and see if it fixes problem

Comment: return null caused a 500 for somereason but not always, only if i did iireset before and that the client cached part was executed. Task.FromResult<Object>(null)  fixed the 500 problem